# Autocorrect for "UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY : Run fsck manually" problem

Tags: boot, 16.04, server, filesystem, fsck

I implemented daily auto-restart of my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server. Most of the time it restarts properly, but sometimes, it shows the following message.

```
inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY : Run fsck manually
(without -a or -p option)
fsck extend with status code 4 done. 
failure: File System check of the root filesystem found.
The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck .
(initramfs):
```

It gets stuck with this error message. Yes, it goes further after I run the command

```
fsck -yf /dev/sda1
```

But this is server, I want to execute this command automatically if any such problem comes and boot into the Ubuntu system, so that I do not need to check the server-status every-time.

Comment: If this happens regularly, you should investigate the cause of the problem though instead of just automating a workaround, especially on a production server. Why are you rebooting daily anyway?

Comment: If you often ends up with this error, you either have a bad disk or the server isn't cleanly shut down. How does your daily auto-restart script look .. and why are you doing it at all ?

Comment: Some services consuming a lot memory (may be memory leak), also creating huge log files if they go on running for long time.   I also carry out system clean and reboot everyday (as cronjob).

Comment: @SorenA I implemented simple restart /sbin/reboot command which runs every midnight which I have defined as cron-job.

Comment: @krishna Why don’t you just restart these services? Daily restart of a Linux server is IMHO an overkill.

Comment: @Melebius if there is not any mechanism to auto-correct disk problem(I thought it is easily doable), I have to disable daily restart. Actually, I got problems in Ubuntu server itself when I run the server for several weeks without restart.

Comment: @krishna Maybe you really have a bad disk. I have one physical Ubuntu server running for 51 days and one virtual running for 296 days at the moment.

Comment: @Melebius but fsck corrects the problem and it boots properly.  It does not happen all the time. Only 1 out of 50 restarts. May be some services are doing crazy things in my hard disk :)